# How to save PDF using ITextSharp?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I working with PDF annotations using ITextSharp. I was able to add annotations pretty smoothly. 
But now I'm trying to edit them. It looks like my PdfReader object is actually updated. But for some reason I can't save it. As shown in the snippet below, I try to get the byte array from using a stamper. The byte array is only 1 byte longer than the previous version no matter how long is the annotation. And when I open the PDF saved on the file system, I still have the old annotation...

```
    private void UpdatePDFAnnotation(string title, string body)
    {
        byte[] newBuffer;
        using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(dataBuffer))
        {

            int pageIndex = 1;
            int annotIndex = 0;

            PdfDictionary pageDict = pdfReader.GetPageN(pageIndex);
            var annots = pageDict.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
            if (annots != null)
            {
                PdfDictionary annot = annots.GetAsDict(annotIndex);
                annot.Put(PdfName.T, new PdfString(title));
                annot.Put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(body));
            }

            // ********************************
            // this line shows the new annotation is in here. Just have to save it somehow !!
            var updatedBody = pdfReader.GetPageN(pageIndex).GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS).GetAsDict(0).GetAsString(PdfName.CONTENTS);
            Debug.Assert(newBody == updatedBody.ToString(), "Annotation body should be equal");


            using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, outStream, '\0', true))
                {
                    newBuffer = outStream.ToArray();
                }
            }

           }
           File.WriteAllBytes( @"Assets\Documents\AnnotedPdf.pdf", newBuffer);
        }
```

Any idea what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Try inserting stamp.Close(); after writing the outStream buffer to newBuffer.

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee *"Try inserting stamp.Close(); after writing the outStream buffer to newBuffer."* - Not *after* but *before*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PdfStamper` does much of the writing at the time it is being closed. This implicitly happens at the end of its `using` block. But you retrieve the `MemoryStream` contents already in that block. Thus, the PDF is not yet written to the retrieved `byte[]`.

Instead either explicitly close the `PdfStamper` instance before retrieving the `byte[]`:

```
using (PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, outStream, '\0', true))
{
    stamp.Close();
    newBuffer = outStream.ToArray();
}
```

or retrieve the `byte[]` *after* that `using` block:

```
using (PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, outStream, '\0', true))
{
}
newBuffer = outStream.ToArray();
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I tried that but not to avail... This drives me crazy since I can check that the PdfReader is up to date but I only get outdated byte array...

Comment: *"I tried that but not to avail"* - What gets written to the file if you do either of the above? If you retrieve the bytes after closing the stamper (and no exception occurs during the closing operation), then `newBuffer` will contain a complete PDF. (Unless you found an iText bug, that is. But I don't think so, that construction is quite common.)

Answer (score 0):

Allright, I finally got it to work. The trick was the two last parameter in the PdfStamper instantiation. I tried it before with only 2 parameters and ended up with a corrupted file. Then I tried again and now it works... here's the snippet

```
    private void UpdatePDFAnnotation(string title, string body)
    {
        using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(dataBuffer))
        {
            PdfDictionary pageDict = pdfReader.GetPageN(pageIndex);
            var annots = pageDict.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);

            PdfDictionary annot = annots.GetAsDict(annotIndex);
            annot.Put(PdfName.T, new PdfString(title));
            annot.Put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(body));

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, ms);    
                stamp.Dispose();                
                dataBuffer = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the output PDF with the additional `'\0', true` parameters is broken then there is something weird already in your original PDF. Other than that those additional parameters can not possibly cause the issue you observe.